# How to queue dask delayed on each workers to allow sequential execution of a process?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I need worker to process a single tasks at a time and finish the current process before starting a new one. I cannot manage to: **(1)** have at most one task running at any moment on each worker, **(2)** make a worker finish a procedure before starting a new one; atomic transactions.

I use dask.distributed Client on a cluster with 40 nodes; 4 cores & 15GB ram each. The pipeline I process have task of around 8-10GB thus having two task on a work will lead to failure of the application.

I tried to assign my workers resource and task allocation with `dask-worker scheduler-ip:port --nprocs 1 --resources process=1` and `futures = [client.submit(func, f, resources={'process': 1}) for f in futures]` but it was with no success.

My code is as following:

```py
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client


@dask.delayed
def load():
  ...


@dask.delayed
def foo():
  ...


@dask.delayed
def save():
  ...

client = Client(scheduler-ip:port)

# Process file from a given path
paths = ['list', 'of', 'path']

results = []
for path in paths:
  img = load(path)

  for _ in range(n):
    img = foo(img)

  results.append(save(output-filename))

client.scatter(results)
futures = client.compute(results)

def identity(x):
  return x
client.scatter(futures)
futures = [client.submit(same, f, resources={'process': 1}) for f in futures]

client.gather(futures)
```

As of right now I have two cases:

1- I run all my inputs and the applications terminates with `MemoryError`

2- I run a subsample however it run as follow:

load(img-1)->load(img-2)->foo(img-1)->load(img-3)->...->save(img-1)->save(img-2)->...

**TLDR: this is what I want to do on each worker:**

**load(img-1)->foo(img-1)->save(img-1)->load(img-7)->...**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing here would probably to be to start your workers with only one thread

```
dask-worker ... --nthreads 1
```

Then that worker will only start one thing at a time